# change the text drag according to some condition - Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hello I am using [gridviewdragdrop](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop) and I wonder if it is possible to change the drag text according to some condition? 
Example: if the node that is caught is empty name field show drag text message: You are not allowed to catch this node because of the name is empty

Answer (score 0):

You mean treeviewdragdrop plugin?
Yes for sure you can. There are a lot of events on drag&drop
In your controller you can add listeners to them:

```
'tree > treeview': {
    'nodedragover': me.onNodeDragOver,
}
or 
    view.on('beforedrop', onBeforeDropNode);
    view.on('drop', onDropNode);
```

Also general event on drag and drop is:

```
    onDragEnter : function(evtObj, targetElId) { //Called when a drag element first intersects another drag/drop element within the 
same drag/drop group. This is where you can code for drop invitation.
         var targetEl =  Ext.get(targetElId);
         targetEl.addCls('dropZoneOver');
     },
     onDragOut : function(evtObj, targetElId) {    
         var targetEl =  Ext.get(targetElId);
         targetEl.toggleCls('dropZoneOver');
     },
     b4StartDrag   : Ext.emptyFn,
     onInvalidDrop : Ext.emptyFn,
     onDragDrop    : Ext.emptyFn,
     endDrag       : Ext.emptyFn
```

Comment: hi @Romick 
The drag and drop is a grid to a tree and the logic is on the side of the grid to take the node.